# Code to add points for multiple players in a game

Tags: python, pandas, list, points

I'm trying to write a simple code to help me keep track of player names and points when playing card games.

```
import pandas as pd

print('Willkommen zum Punkterechner!')

#asking for number of players 
p_count = int(input("Anzahl der Spieler?: "))
p_list = []
points = [0]*p_count

#asking for name of players in range of number of players 
for i in range(p_count):
    p_name = input('Wie lautet der Name von Spieler ' + str(i+1) + '?: ')
    p_list.append(p_name)

d = {'Spieler': p_list, 'Punkte': points}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

current_round = 1

for i,j in enumerate(p_list):
    points_round = int(input('Punkte für ' + j + ' in Runde ' + str(current_round) + ': '))
    points[i] += points_round

print(df)
```

Now I need help finding a way to sum the points for each round/each player. I also want to keep updating the current_round until something like `input('Keep Playing?')` is 'No'.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up your dictionary `d` to have player IDs as keys, and points as values, like so:

```
d = {k: v for k,v in zip(p_list, points)}
```

Then when player with ID `j` 'scores' `n` points, you can just do `d[j] += n`

Here's your game set up that way (you probably know how to do the necessary to print a nice dataframe instead of the raw dictionary in my code). I added some sample code to handle the optional further rounds.

```
import pandas as pd
import operator

print('Willkommen zum Punkterechner!')

#asking for number of players 
p_count = int(input("Anzahl der Spieler?: "))
p_list = range(1, p_count+1)
points = [0]*p_count
d = {k: v for k,v in zip(p_list, points)}

def play_round(current_round=1):
    for player in d.keys():
        points_round = int(input('Punkte für ' + str(player) + ' in Runde ' + str(current_round) + ': '))
        d[player] += points_round
    print(d)

    if input('Noch ein Spiel?') == 'Nein':
        winner = max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        print(f'Der Gewinner ist {winner} mit {d[winner]} Punkten!') 
        return
    else:
        play_round(current_round+1)

play_round()
```